# How to install PerlMagick on Mac OSX using Homebrew?

Tags: macos, perl, imagemagick, homebrew

I have successfully installed ImageMagick using Homebrew but I can't get PerlMagick to install properly using the instructions here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

I get a lot of errors on Magick.xs. Anyone has any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10661085/edit) to provide the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892362/error-installing-imagemagick-with-homebrew#11974704), I simply uninstalled mono (which brew doctor had been complaining about), un- and reinstalled brew imagemagick.

cpanm then reported Image::Magick to already be installed. And it worked, too.