# Error installing imagemagick with homebrew

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I'm trying to install imagemagick via home brew and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Failed executing: make install (imagemagick.rb:97)
These existing issues may help you:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13618
Otherwise, this may help you fix or report the issue:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/bug-fixing-checklist
```

I've completely uninstalled xcode and reinstalled it and command line tools and its still throwing this error.

`brew doctor` is thorwing some warnings:

```
Warning: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework detected
This can be picked up by CMake's build system and likely cause the build to
fail. You may need to move this file out of the way to compile CMake.
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libcdt.5.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libcgraph.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libgraph.5.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libgvc.6.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libgvpr.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libpathplan.4.dylib     /usr/local/lib/libxdot.4.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcdt.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libcgraph.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgraph.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvc.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libgvpr.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpathplan.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libxdot.pc
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

2to3
pkg-config

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.
Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
/usr/bin/pkg-config => /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/bin/pkg-config

This was most likely created by the Mono installer. `./configure` may
have problems finding brew-installed packages using this other pkg-config.
```

Do you think any of those could be the problem?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I am running Lion.
Brew is up to date.

Comment: None of the mono warnings from brew doctor would make me worried. Personally, I'd resolve the PATH one and see if you still get the same failure.

Comment: @remear how do I go about that?

Comment: Figure out which of ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc and see if any of those have statements in them involving setting PATH. you'll want to either place or move if it's already in there, "/usr/local/bin" at the beginning of your path. So, it'll end up looking like

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

or it might look like

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/path/to/more/stuff

(can't seem to get the formatting right =/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hit the same issue yesterday, and in my case the solution surprisingly resulted in a combination of uninstalling the Mono Framework following [Uninstalling Mono on Mac OS X](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX#Uninstalling_Mono_on_Mac_OS_X), removing all packages that placed unexpected dynlibs and .pc files (which in my case were fuse-related).

However, I did have the PATH set according to homebrew's wishes, amending `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I can't say this works because I am unwilling to uninstall mono, but it seems to be working for other people so I will accept this answer.